# How can I upgrade CIDER to 0.8?

Tags: emacs, clojure, cider

The latest version of CIDER on MELPA is 0.7. The latest on Github is 0.8, which hasn't been pushed MELPA.

What is the best way for me to upgrade CIDER given these circumstances? I'm relatively new to emacs, so please be detailed in your description of what exactly to do.

Edit: I realized my problem. My init file defined MELPA referring to its Melpa-Stable server. The regular server appears to be more up to date.

Answer (score 6):

There's no CIDER 0.8 yet; 0.7 is still the last stable release.

If you don't mind occasional breakages you can simply switch from MELPA Stable to MELPA (the package there tracks CIDER's `master` branch) and that will be enough (of course, you'll also have to update `cider-nrepl` to 0.8.0-SNAPSHOT).